# Permission sets metadata xml - some field permissions missing

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, permission-sets

In the permission set metadata xml in my eclipse project, `fieldPermissions` for some of the fields of an object are missing. Please note that:

1. The object is included as a part of the force.com IDE project - hence the permission set xml contains  for some fields,  for the object and  for the object's tab too. Its just some of these fields which are missing.
2. The missing fields are not standard audit fields, they are custom fields.

Please share your thoughts on why the fieldpermission metadata of some of the fields could be missing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields won't be included if the field is universally required, including master-detail relationships. This is specifically called out in [Permission Set | Metadata API Developer's Guide | Salesforce Developers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm#PermissionSetFieldPermissions_title):

> PermissionSetFieldPermissions represents the field permissions for users assigned to a permission set. In API version 30.0 and later, permissions for required fields can’t be retrieved or deployed.

If you want/need those fields, use a lower API version.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox . This makes total sense, haven't considered the required factor before.

Comment: @Stygon I only remember this because I was in the middle of some very intense permissions clean up when they released this "feature" and it made my life just a bit more difficult because fields would appear and disappear depending on which package.xml file I was using at the time... It's probably best to just ignore those fields.